# MongoDB Group by users having not performed event x

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a events collection. I want users who did not perform event click.
Example -

```
collection - 
{
   'event' : 'open'
   'user' : 1
},
{
   'event' : 'open'
   'user' : 2
},
{
   'event' : 'click'
   'user' : 2
}
```

I want result as following :

```
{ 'user' : 1 }
```

What i am getting is :

```
{ 'user' : 1 },
{ 'user' : 2 }
```

My Code :

```
$collection->aggregate(array(
     array('$match' =>  array('$event' => array('$not' => 'click')) ),
     array('$group' => 
              array(
                '_id' => '$user'
              ),
    )
))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should first group the documents and then filter the user who havent clicked and then project the result in your preferred format.

```
$collection->aggregate(array(
 array('$group' => 
              array(
                '_id' => '$user','events' => array('$push'=>'event')
              ),
     array('$match' =>  array('$events' => array('$not' => 'click')) ),
         array('$project' =>  array('user' => '$user') ),

))
```

Comment: Thanks. I understood. Its just about the sequence. We are first grouping the data and then applying the conditions on that grouped data.